# Sonata Admin Custom field with data transformer

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a easy form with a data transformer, it works correctly (update, persist and delete) but I get a error on twig.

Impossible to invoke a method ("trans") on a NULL variable ("") in SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:CRUD:edit_orm_one_to_many.html.twig at line 30

error is in this line:

`{{ nested_field.vars['sonata_admin'].admin.trans(nested_field.vars.label) }}`

All fields have value in nested_field.vars['sonata_admin'] less my custom field

My code is this:

```
    $formMapper
            ->add(
                $formMapper->create('articleAmount', 'text')
                    ->addModelTransformer($articleAmountToStringTransformer)
            )
           ...
```

Entities

```
    /**
     * AppShopHasArticles
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="app_shop_has_articles")
     * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nvia\ShopAppBundle\Entity\Repository\AppShopHasArticlesRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     */
    class AppShopHasArticles
    {

        /**
         * @var \Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Article
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nvia\ShopAppBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="appShopHasArticles")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @Expose
         */
        private $article;

        /**
         * @var \Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Country
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Country")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @Expose
         */
        private $country;

        /**
         * @var \Nvia\ShopAppBundle\Entity\AppShop
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nvia\ShopAppBundle\Entity\ArticleAmount")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id", nullable=false),
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="article_id", nullable=false)
         * })
         * @Expose
         */
        private $articleAmount;


        ...
    }

    /**
     * ArticleAmount
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="article_amount")
     */
    class ArticleAmount
    {
        /**
         * @var \Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Article
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nvia\ShopAppBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="articleAmounts")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        private $article;

        /**
         * @var \Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Country
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nvia\CommonBundle\Entity\Country")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         */
        private $country;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
         * @Expose
         */
        private $amount;


        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
         */
        private $createdAt;

    }
```

What am I doing wrong :/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the create method of the formMapper sonata will not insert it's own logic.

Instead try something like this

```
   $formMapper
        ->add('articleAmount', 'text')
        ->get('articleAmount')
        ->addModelTransformer($articleAmountToStringTransformer)
```

Tested on Sonata 2.4